# Failed to establish a connection Coinbase commerce webhook

Tags: php, coinbase-api

i have problem with coinbase webhook link. All worked good, but yesterday webhook link was disabled, after test, i've got message from coinbase: Failed to establish a connection to the remote server at www.mysite.com
I'm using Goddaddy hosting with cpanel. Maybe coinbase ip was blocked by godaddy? I tried other links (digitalocean and other free webhook sites) for webhook and they worked correctly.

> header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

was sent correctly.
No any ip addresses in cpanel IP/ban list founded.

Comment: Please am experiencing the same issue and i have contacted them but to no avail they haven't responded yet for over two weeks now, what was the solution they shared

Answer (score 0):

I think your domain's SSL is expired.

Comment: thank you! ssl is ok. I contact coinbase support and problem was fixed.

Comment: Sounds good, if they have shared the cause of the problem then please share